# how to crate a list of days from x date till y date by adding 7 days?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have tried this code but showing nothing while checking the list length

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
sdate= date(1990,10,25)
tdate=date(1990,10,25)
i=7
rqd_dt=[]
adate = date(2022,12,31)
while adate > tdate:
    rqd_dt.append(tdate)
    tdate = sdate+timedelta(days=i)  
print(len(rqd_dt))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mistake only. Change this line:

`tdate = sdate+timedelta(days=i)`
to
`tdate = tdate+timedelta(days=i)`

This way, `tdate` keeps incrementing by 7 days. As you had it, `tdate` remains the same every loop, so it's not stuck at the print statement - it's stuck in an infinite loop. If you added a little investigative print statement inside your `while` loop, you would see this.

Comment: thanks its working  1680 number of days